# ActionbarSherlock not showing menu icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Not sure if this has been covered for this specific instance but here goes:

Upgraded my app to use the latest version of ActionBarSherlock (4.3.0) for the benefits of backwards compatibility.

On a Samsung Galaxy Note 2(w/Android 4.1.2), the hard overflow menu triggers the menu, but does not include the icons for the menu items.

On a 2.3.3 device the overflow menu shows the menu icons (fine), and for a 3.2 tablet device I had to hack the menu code (instructions from another forum post) to show the icons in the overflow.

Anyone else run into this and is there a solution to get the icons to show on the 4.1.2 platform?  I'm trying to get the menu to behave consistently so far as to show the Icon_Title pairs for menu items in the over flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since honeycomb, the settings/overflow does not contain the icons.

Comment: That certainly seems like an odd item to drop from the feature set.  Even the new Share Action dropdown includes icons for the related share providers.     So to be clear, Honeycomb and newer api only allow for icons in the actionbar itself, while icons in the overflow will not display.   My guess is that the only way around this is to create a custom popup menu widget.  Further, just to point out, I dont think the API document or even the action bar design document makes this change clear.

Comment: You are correct with this on all counts. It's kind of odd having come from 2.x era putting effort into those icons, to simultaneously be given the screen real estate in the form of an action bar to show those actions more prominently, but it is then absent from the overflow. On larger screens, more of those overflow options obviously don't overflow, so it's still somewhat important to provide the icon for at least the first 3 maybe 4 options...

Comment: ok, thanks for helping to clarify that.  I've marked as accepted and hopefully this will help explain for anyone else who runs into this issue as well.